# Aggregating, Ranking, Binning, Renaming, Each Column in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How can we write a function that will aggregate, rank, bin each column of the df, rename the aggregated by adding a prefix, ranked, and binned columns, then join the new rank & bin columns to the df?

```
Import pandas as pd
data = {"index_id": range(101, 131),
        'company': ['Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera',
                    'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox',
                    'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari',
                    'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave',
                    'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome'],
        "rating": [4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3,
                   4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5,
                   1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2,
                   1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5,
                   5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.groupby(['company']).agg({'rating':['std', 'mean']})
df.columns = ['rating_std', 'rating_mean']
df_rank = df.rank(ascending = 0, method = 'dense').add_prefix('rank_')
output = df_rank.copy(deep=True)
bin_labels = ['Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum', 'Diamond']
output['bin_rank_rating_std'] = pd.qcut(output['rank_rating_std'],
                              q=[0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1],
                              labels=bin_labels)
output['bin_rank_rating_mean'] = pd.qcut(output['rank_rating_mean'],
                              q=[0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1],
                              labels=bin_labels)
```

In df_rank, I was able to rank the standard deviation and mean, then add the prefix of rank, but couldn't figure out how to bin and rename each ranked column without writing down each column. I want to write a function or use a for-loop because w/ my original dataset. I have 30 columns I'll be ranking and binning, so I can't name each one in a function. The dataframe output will be how it should look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with lambda function, then [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
#simplify for not necessary set new columns names by list
df = df.groupby(['company'])['rating'].agg(['std', 'mean']).add_prefix('rating_')

df_rank = df.rank(ascending = 0, method = 'dense').add_prefix('rank_')

bin_labels = ['Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum', 'Diamond']
output = df_rank.apply(lambda x:pd.qcut(x, q=[0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1], labels=bin_labels))
output = df_rank.join(output.add_prefix('bin_'))
print (output)
         rank_rating_std  rank_rating_mean bin_rank_rating_std  \
company                                                          
Brave                1.0               4.0              Bronze   
Chrome               5.0               1.0             Diamond   
Firefox              2.0               2.0              Silver   
Opera                4.0               3.0            Platinum   
Safari               3.0               5.0                Gold   

        bin_rank_rating_mean  
company                       
Brave               Platinum  
Chrome                Bronze  
Firefox               Silver  
Opera                   Gold  
Safari               Diamond
```